# Sending message, they show up in red

Tags: ipad

I've been messaging with someone from my iPad to their phone for over a year, but now they show up in red. My messages cannot be sent. 
I know it's not on their end because it happens with other people too. 
How do I correct this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 1):

Double check they have iMessage activated in their Settings. Sometimes changing SIM card when travelling can remove a number you have been using for iMessage before, or people don't reconfirm it afterwards.